# Yii2 weird i18n message/extract behavior

Tags: yii2, internationalization, extract

I just created a new Yii2 advanced project with the suggested command:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced sdcac

(sdcac is the project name)

Following https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n I tried to "extract" all i18n messages from my app.

From root folder I executed this command to create config file:

> ./yii message/config --languages=en,es --messagePath=messages
> console/config/i18n.php

It generated this:

```php
return [
    'color' => null,
    'interactive' => true,
    'help' => false,
    'silentExitOnException' => null,
    'sourcePath' => '@yii',
    'messagePath' => 'messages',
    'languages' => [
        'en',
        'es',
    ],
    'translator' => [
        'Yii::t',
        '\\Yii::t',
    ],
    'sort' => false,
    'overwrite' => true,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'markUnused' => true,
    'except' => [
        '.*',
        '/.*',
        '/messages',
        '/tests',
        '/runtime',
        '/vendor',
        '/BaseYii.php',
    ],
    'only' => [
        '*.php',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'db' => 'db',
    'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%source_message}}',
    'messageTable' => '{{%message}}',
    'catalog' => 'messages',
    'ignoreCategories' => [],
    'phpFileHeader' => '',
    'phpDocBlock' => null,
];
```

Then, I tried to "extract" all the messages from my project running:

> ./yii message/extract console/config/i18n.php

But it only finds Yii texts on "vendor" folder, although it's listed on "except" param:

[Yii2 console extract command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aykGc.png)

For example, it misses this message on "views/site/index.php" file:

> \Yii::t('app', 'Give it a try!')

I can't understand why. What's wrong? Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's looking inside of vendor folder is this part of config:

```php
'sourcePath' => '@yii',
```

This is telling the extractor that it should look where `@yii` alias is pointing. Which is the directory where the `BaseYii.php` of framework is located.

That's fine if you want to translate strings in framework. But, if you want to translate strings in your own code you have to change `sourcePath` to point to root directory of your project.

For example if your config is located in `console/config` folder:

```php
'sourcePath' => dirname(__DIR__, 2),
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But that config file was automatically created by "message/config" command. Is that a bug?

Comment: It's not exactly bug. The `message/config` command uses `@yii` as `sourcePath` because it's default value. You can use `--source-path` option or its short form `-s` to set the `sourcePath` when using that command. You can check `yii help message/config` to see all options of that command.